# Generating Google Spreadsheet Links from cell contents

Tags: google-sheets

You previously answered a part of my question, but I am looking to modify this behavior in multiple rows of column A so I don't want to manually correct it.

In A2 I have:

```
/mylist/groceries/index.html
```

In B2 I use concatenate

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https//mylife.com",A2),A2)
```

This creates the link I need, and returns the same text that is in A2, but I want just the first portion without the/index.html to be viewable.

```
/mylist/groceries
```

I do not want the `"/index.html"` to show

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Clear Column B entirely, then place the following array formula into cell B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,HYPERLINK("https//mylife.com"&A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"/index.html",""))))`

This should process everything in Column A as you would like.